# beginner regex expressions for bit strings

Tags: regex

I have included what I need to express - my attempt at the solution.

for strings of 0's and 1's:

the strings that contain exactly one 1 - (0*)(1)(0*)

the strings with two or more 0's or 1's followed by two or more 0's - (0|1){2}(0|1)* (0){2}(0*)

the strings that contain 01 - (0|1)* (01) (0|1)*

Am not sure how to express "contain" because what I'm doing seems kind of redundant. Am I somewhat on the right track with these?

Comment: Could you try to provide example data, and examples of what you are looking for?

Comment: I have no idea what your question means. What kind of strings are you after *exactly*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go to your answers:

the strings that contain exactly one 1 = `1{1}` {N} is a quantifier can be

{n} exact

{n,} from n to infinite

{n,m} from n to m

the strings with two or more 0's or 1's followed by two or more 0's
`(0{2,}0{2,})|(1{2,}0{2,})` I did not use `[01]{2,}` because the expression will validate on 1000 which, i think is wrong.

the strings that contain 01 - `01`

Always keep it simple.

Comment: So for contains, 01 looks like it only expresses 01 and nothing else. Would it actually work for strings like 000001 0010010 010001 111010 as well? Do you not have to account for any other bits that might occur before you actually get the 01?

Comment: @TidusSmith For the first question, It depends on how the OP would use the expression, to match an exact string: no it wont, but to match the desired groups (like some sort of indexOf or substr) yeah it will. For the second question: I don't really know. Just did the expressions that the OP asked, if you read his question there is nothing more than the especifics problems.